# como puedo saber si un registro de una tabla esta siendo referenciado en otra

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo dos tablas, una es un registro para un "login" y otra es los datos del "login"; lo que quiero es que por ejemplo si el usuario crea su "login" pero no sus "datos" (o sea que el usuario haya regresado a la página de inicio sin completar la tabla de sus datos) esto hace que el registro de el "login" no tenga una referencia fk en la tabla de "datos"

Entonces estuve pensado en un query para saber si los datos de la tabla login tienen un fk en la tabla "datos", si no tiene un fk significa que el registro de el login está sin datos; lo cual lanzaría una función para eliminar ese registro de login.

No se si me explique bien; en conclusión, lo que necesito es saber si un dato de una tabla está referenciado en otra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el operador `not exists`, para traer aquellos registros de la tabla de `login` que no tienen un registro correspondiente en la tabla `datos`, por ejemplo:

```
select *
  from login
 where not exists (select 1 from datos where datos.login = login.login)
```

También puedes utilizar el operador `not in` para obtener estos mismos registros, por ejemplo:

```
select * 
  from login
 where login.login not in (select login from datos)
```

En ambos casos, estoy asumiendo que en la tabla datos el campo que hace referencia a la tabla login se llama también login, y que en la tabla login el campo de la llave primaria también se llama login.

Esto, porque no queda claro en tu imagen cuáles son dichos campos.

Un saludo.

Comment: gracias amigo es justo lo que necesitaba, la imagen solo lo puse como referencia, porque mi tabla estaba un poco compleja, pero al final si funciono, muchas graciass